# Что обозначает "ww0ww" и "www" в конфигурации?

Tags: freebsd, asterisk, телефония

Разбираю чужую конфигурацию Asterisk и встретил в плане набора такое объявление:

```
exten => _9[12]XX,10,Dial(DAHDI/3/www${EXTEN:1})

exten => _0ZXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(DAHDI/g1/ww0ww${EXTEN:1})
```

Что обозначает "ww0ww" и "www"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

w - пауза/задержка 0.5 сек., чтобы дождаться ответа станции.

Это дает небольшую задержку при передаче номера станции в первом случае, похоже, для звонка на внутренние, во втором - для выхода на межгород.